# How to handle contentiously querying in android Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am deleting the student records continuously based on  student enrollment id

I am having 1000 id's I am deleting continuously as shown below..

```
for (int j = 0; j < feeDetailsArrayList.size(); j++) {
               FeeDetails feeDetails = feeDetailsArrayList.get(j);
                           dbHelper.deleteFeeDetailsTableRecords(feeDetails.getStudentEnrollmentId());
        }

public  void deleteFeeDuesTableRecords(String studentEnrollmentId){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "delete from "+ STUDENT_FEE_DUES_TABLE +" where "+ KEY_STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_ID + "  = " + "'" + studentEnrollmentId + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


}
```

**It will shows following error**

```
fillWindow() exception unable to open database file (code 14)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:854)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
```

what was the problem am not able to trace,can any one guide me
Your response will be appreciated.

Comment: The code in your question seems to be missing the actual error location, namely the `fillWindow()` method. Also: You got an "*unable to open database file*" error, hence: Show us the code that opens the database. Most likely this is an permission issue (e.g. wrong path for db file)

Comment: @pskink,@dhke Thanks for response.The issue is Fixed by the using sql IN(id1,id2...idn)